# Salt grains reported by minion differ form those reported to master

Tags: salt-stack

I have a minion with id *app1*. It has the following grains as reported locally via `salt-call -g` and which are corroborated by its minion file:

```
id: app1
datacenter: dc1
master: saltmaster1
prototypes: application
...
```

where **datacenter** and **prototypes** are custom grains.

From *saltmaster1*, I run `salt 'app1' cmd.run "echo 'yo' | wall"` to make sure that I am talking to the correct minion and I see the wall message on *app1*. I then test that I can ping *app1* and that it will respond `salt 'app1' test.ping` and it responds `True`. Now I run `salt 'app1' grains.items` from *saltmaster1* and it displays the following values:

```
id: app1
master: saltmaster1
prototypes: application
...
```

The **datacenter** grain is missing! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the salt-minion service and waited a few minutes.